# How to solve overallocating memory with command buffers in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

It's generally recommended to reuse command buffers. So let's say I keep a list of command buffers that are ready to be used, so I do:

```
CmdBuffer cmd_buffer = getCmdBuffer();
/* start recording*/ 
/* Record 10,000 commands */

CmdBuffer cmd_buffer2 = getCmdBuffer();
/* start recording */
/* Record 10 commands */
```

These command buffers are executed and then eventually returned to the available list. The first command buffer (having recorded 10,000 commands) takes up more memory in the pool than the second one. When the command buffer is reset it doesn't return the memory to the pool, that memory is still occupied. Then at another point, I need to record 50,000 commands, so I call getCmdBuffer() and the command buffer that's returned is the one that I had previously recorded only 10 commands in. As I'm recording into this command buffer (I issue command 11, 12... etc) the command buffer grows and more memory is occupied/allocated in the pool as required.

The above method results in likely every command buffer, eventually, having enough memory allocated for the highest number of commands that your program consistently records over and over again in your loop. ie., If on average your program records 100,000 commands into a buffer, then eventually every buffer will be big enough to hold that many.

Conceptually I think this is like storing things in vectors. You get one and you start pushing back, it resized according to requirement. The reset command buffer in Vulkan is equivalent to calling clear(), but it still holds onto the memory allocated. If you decide to 'free' the command buffer as opposed to resetting it, then this is similar to clearing the vector so that its size is 0, then calling vector::shrink_to_fit() so that any memory isn't wasted. The problem with this is that then the vector/command buffer has to allocate new memory a whole bunch of times.

Comment: "*When the command buffer is reset it doesn't return the memory to the pool, that memory is still occupied.*" How do you know that? Even if you replace the pool's allocators, that would only show when the *pool* returns memory to *your allocators*, not whether or not memory given to a CB is returned to the pool.

Comment: @NicolBolas "How do you know that?" I remember reading it a couple of places. I think I was in the waking state. I think the system gets the memory back when you "free" the buffer

Answer (score 3):

Allocate command buffers with a similar life-time from the same pool, and then call `vkResetCommandPool()` to reset all of them and re-pool the memory for future allocations. Pipeline pool allocation using multiple pools to ensure that you can do this with minimal management overhead.

In the grand scheme of graphics memory requirements the command stream is tiny (i.e. 100K commands is probably less than 1MB) so don't get too concerned about a small amount of overallocation.

In reality the driver pool implementation is likely caching memory allocations anyway, because allocations on the critical path for a frame are terrible for performance, so even if you clear the tail of a command buffer or clear a pool the memory is still likely tied up by the pool.

Comment: I don't understand people emphasising that if you don't have the command buffer reset bit, meaning individual command buffers can't be reset individually, but you're forced to reset the entire command pool, that this can be efficient because then the driver can use a simple linear allocator. I don't get this. If I allocate a command buffer, issue two commands, then allocate another command buffer, and issue two commands, then issue more commands on the first command buffer, how is that possibly going to be implemented as a linear allocator? Furthermore I don't understand whether the command ..

Comment: ... buffers are linked blocks to newly allocated memory when they get to big, or it's one big buffer, and moved to new memory like std::vector does. Either way with multiple command buffers I don't understand how it can possibly be a linear allocator

Comment: Most probable implementation: 

(1) Command pool manages a pool of fixed size memory chunks.

(2) Command buffers grab chunks from the pool when they need to. When a chunk is full a new one gets pulled from the pool. Driver inserts some form of internal "jump" command as the last command in the old chunk, to branch to the new chunk.

(3) It's effectively a linear allocator in terms of performance (lockless linear allocation within each chunk), with a slight overhead whenever you allocate a new chunk.

Comment: In either case, drivers are doing all sorts of magic for you here under the hood to make command buffers cheap - don't worry about trying to second guess it.